# I can not view my ionic app on ionic view in iphone

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I created an ionic app and deployed on ionic.io by following steps.

```
>ionic upload
```

This is a new project and I copied www directory from old project and pasted them to new project.
I can run this project successfully in local.
After uploading this on ionic.io, I can now run this app by tapping "view app" option in ionic view with the error message "VIEW ERROR. STATUS: 404"
I want to fix this asap.
Thanks.

Comment: I got this from trying to upload with slow wifi even though it showed a successful upload. Any luck since?

Comment: I have the same problem....Have you fixed that?

Comment: Sorry. Not solved yet

Comment: Android seems ok. But iPhone sucks for this. Ionic View is so buggy! Normally the problem fixes itself over time. But it's the biggest gripe I have with Ionic. If all else fails ionic link a new app id and upload that! Sync to Latest.. Always getting connection failures...

Comment: Or you get No Connection...

Comment: @Jin Hong ionic `upload` currently deprecated. you need to push from git.